# How to sum a bunch of numeric fields in an array of objects in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Below is my stage output after I did a `$lookup` in an aggregate query:

```
"projects": [
        {
            "_id": "609d1a10b588c73aeee9aac9",
            "projectType": "public",
            "status": "completed",
            "amt_paid": 100,
            "revisionStatus": false,
            "commission": 20,
            "engineer_submission": "true",
            "revenueOnRevision": 10
        },
        {
            "_id": "609d3754b588c73aeee9aae8",
            "projectType": "public",
            "status": "open",
            "amt_paid": 50,
            "totalBids": 0,
            "revisionStatus": false,
            "commission": 30,
            "engineer_submission": "false",
            "revenueOnRevision": 100
        }
    ]
```

Desired Output:

```
   "projects": [
        {
            "_id": "609d1a10b588c73aeee9aac9",
            "projectType": "public",
            "status": "completed",
            "amt_paid": 100,
            "revisionStatus": false,
            "commission": 20,
            "engineer_submission": "true",
            "revenueOnRevision": 10
        },
        {
            "_id": "609d3754b588c73aeee9aae8",
            "projectType": "public",
            "status": "open",
            "amt_paid": 50,
            "totalBids": 0,
            "revisionStatus": false,
            "commission": 30,
            "engineer_submission": "false",
            "revenueOnRevision": 100
        }
    ],
    totalAmt : 310
```

the field `totalAmt` gets its value by adding (`amt_paid` + `revenueOnRevision` + `commission`) of every element in the array and summing it all up.

Tried doing:

```
$set : {
  $sum : {
       $add : ['$projects.amt_paid', '$projects.commission', '$projects.revenueOnRevision']  
       }
     }
```

I don't understand why the above stage wont work. Would appreciate if someone could point out my mistake or show me the correct way to solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I don't understand why the above stage wont work.*

When we select embedded field of array `projects.amt_paid`, it will result array of elements means numbers as per your sample data, so `$add` wont sum nested array of numbers directly,

First you need to sum array of numbers using `$sum` and then use `$add`/`$sum` to sum,

```
  {
    $set: {
      totalAmt: {
        $add: [
          { $sum: "$projects.amt_paid" },
          { $sum: "$projects.commission" },
          { $sum: "$projects.revenueOnRevision" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dYrppKb76Xe)

---

There are different ways to do this kind of operation, you can use `$concatArrays` to concat all three array fields and then `$sum`

```
  {
    $set: {
      totalAmt: {
        $sum: {
          $concatArrays: [
            "$projects.amt_paid",
            "$projects.commission",
            "$projects.revenueOnRevision"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GEqbTJasO87)

Comment: thanks a lot turivishal. I understood why it does not work.